# WSO2 certificate setup for service provider

Tags: wso2, x509certificate, saml-2.0, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

We are using the Spring-SAML extension to implement our SSO POC.  I've got it working perfectly going against ssocircle.com as our IdP.  We now want to bring the IdP internal, so we have chosen WSO2 as our I.S.  I'm at the beginning/setup stage and the main issue I'm having is the "Certificate Alias" selection under "Register New Service Provider" in the web based management console.  The Spring-SAML default config points to a JKS named "samlKeystore.jks".  I'm still using this because I'm still in a test/POC mode.  In order to register the SP for the WSO2 IS, I believe I need to be able to import the default cert used in samlKeystore.jks.  I've exported the Apollo key and have imported it into wso2carbon.jks.  The cert does show up in the Certificate Alias selection list, and I can select it.  However, after saving, it always **resets** back to the wso2carbon.cert.  I'm thinking something is wrong with my cert or the export/import procedure I'm employing.  Does anyone have some insight here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the `Enable Signature Validation in Authentication Requests and Logout Requests` in addition to selecting the alias. Otherwise the alias is of no use and won't be saved. (When there is no value saved for alias it shows the `wso2carbon.cert` by default).

Comment: The above is the correct analysis.  Too bad the Management Console GUI does not give some sort of feedback that choice selected will not be saved.